# Django - Add custom fields to records

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Suppose we have a Mode `Table` with common fields (id, name, date_creation)

```
class Table(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    date_creation = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Some `Tables` must have a "Wheels" attribute (eg: `wheels="plastic"`), while other tables do not require this attribute and require something else.

eg :

```
Table 1: id = ..., name = ..., date_creation = ..., wheels = "plastic"
Table 2: id = ..., name = ..., date_creation = ..., feet = "wood"
```

How can i manage this extrafields in Django in order to deserve them in Django Rest Framework?

Answer (score 1):

You can just add all the custom fields and make them nullable, then just filter the available fields with an `if` statement.